# Публикация Android библиотеки с зависимостями на приватные репозитории

Tags: android, maven, library, aar

В разработке библиотеки под Android используем другую aar библиотеку из внутреннего приватного репозитория:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    api 'ru.company.privatelibrary:1.0.0'
    ...
}
```

Если опубликовать такую библиотеку в публичном репозитории, то зависимости на внутреннюю либу не будут разрешены. Есть ли варианты включения сторонней либы в свой aar?